# cofinite topology,standard topology,half-open interval topology

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

1.$R$ be equipped with the **cofinite** topology. Is $R$ connected?

2.$R$ be equipped with the **standard** topology. Is $R$ connected?

3.$R$ be equipped with the **half-open interval** topology. Is $R$ connected?

I think that **3** is FALSE. but I don't know that **1**,**2** are connected

How should i prove that first and second are **connected**?

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: The theorem "connected iff no proper clopen sets" may help you. https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Connected_iff_no_Proper_Clopen_Sets

Comment: For (1), every pair of non-empty open sets has a non-empty intersection. For (2) a continuous and surjective function from $\mathbb{R}$ to the discrete space $\{0,1\}$ gives a contradiction with the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: Tank you all. I understand perpectly!

Comment: 1.  Usually but not always.

Comment: In 3. if you mean the $\subseteqq$-topology $T$ such that $T\supset \{[a,b):a,b\in \Bbb R\},$  which is also called the lower-limit topology on $\Bbb R, $ and also called the Sorgenfry line, then the sets $(-\infty, 0$) and $[0,\infty) $ are open, disjoint, and non-empty and their union is the whole space. Observe that $(-\infty,0)=\cup_{r<0}[r,0)\in T$ and $[0,\infty)=\cup_{r>0}[0,r)\in T.$